# how to fix pipeline gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to make a gitlab pipeline. so that at each push the repository is checked for the validity
of the pipeline code:

```
image: docker:dind

stages:
  - test
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cp -r ./ /golang_app/
    - cd /golang_app/
    - chmod +x /golang_app/run-tests.sh /golang_app/scripts/test_in_docker.sh
    - chdir /golang_app/  
    - /bin/sh ./run-tests.sh
  tags:
    - docker
```

in file run-tests.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run \
    -v $(pwd):/tests \
    golang:1.16.6-alpine3.14 \
    /tests/scripts/test_in_docker.sh
```

in my repository:

```
total 68
drwxrwxrwx    5 root     root          4096 Dec 12 16:26 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root          4096 Dec 12 14:22 ..
drwxrwxrwx    6 root     root          4096 Dec 12 16:26 .git
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root            77 Dec 12 14:22 .gitignore
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           171 Dec 12 16:26 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           267 Dec 12 14:22 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1071 Dec 12 14:22 LICENSE
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root          1630 Dec 12 14:22 README.md
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root          4096 Dec 12 14:22 cmd
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           190 Dec 12 14:22 docker-compose.yaml
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root           107 Dec 12 14:22 go.mod
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root         13518 Dec 12 14:22 go.sum
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           117 Dec 12 14:22 run-tests.sh
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Dec 12 14:22 scripts
```

I get this in the gitlab-runner log, as soon as I haven't tried to run it already, I don't want to

```
$ /bin/sh ./run-tests.sh
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/tests/scripts/test_in_docker.sh": stat /tests/scripts/test_in_docker.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.
time="2021-12-12T17:24:22Z" level=error msg="error waiting for container: context canceled"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
stages:
- test

test:
stage: test
script:
- /bin/sh ./run-tests.sh
tags:
- shell-runner
```